# Simple method for cluster analysis

Tags: clustering, neural-networks, algorithms

One of the academic's at the university where I am studying has conducted research on organisational sustainability. He approached me to turn his research into software that can be used for consulting purposes.

The general idea is that the members of an organisation sign up and take the survey online. The survery has 8 dimensions (diversity, innovative potential, conplexity and so on), and each dimension has 10 questions. Each question must be answered on a scale of 1 -5 agree/disagree. There are no averages/totals or calculations taken on the scores.

I then need to do a cluster analsysis of some sorts. The requirement is that the number of clusters can be selected, and then a nice diagram is presented showing the clusters, and this will then be used to show if there is divergence/convergence in the organisation, and as a basis for further consulting (i.e remedies if there are clusters of differing values on say diversity).

What I need is a suitable simple and mainstream method for the cluster analysis.
The academic suggested neural networks but this seemed to be really difficult to use for cluster analysis (statistics is not my major so I am skating on thin ice here). Wikipedia throws up things like K Means and so on, but I am too green in stats to decide what is what.

The only requirement that I have is that it must be mainstream and give results that are easy to visualize using a javascript library such as D3.

Comment: I would consult http://www.amstat.org/about/ethicalguidelines.cfm which seems to bear directly on what you propose.

Comment: @NickCox that is similar, but the questions already exist, I am just looking for a way to take the survey results and do a cluster analysis and visualise the clusters.

Comment: This is not much more precise than proposing to do some data analysis and graph the results. There are many ways to do cluster analysis, either directly or after some multivariate analysis. In addition, clustering prejudges the issue of whether groups exist in any strong sense.  It would seem prudent for you to evaluate several methods both for clustering and for graphics before offering this as a consultancy service.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will pass it on to the academic. Just to clarify, I am not offering this as a consultancy service, I am just the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good peer-reviewed and published papers on multivariate control using Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM's).

GMM's are a basis, like sine and cosine function in the Fourier series, so with enough data, you can approximate any other continuous distribution to arbitrary precision.  It is not a bad starting point.

Once you have the GMM you can look at things like "membership in clusters", "locations of lines of equal probability of membership", and the "GMM parameter values (weights, means, variances)".

The cluster membership is highly graphable.

EDIT:

I think that when a non-scientist says "mainstream" as you have quoted, what they really mean is that it must be a credible/legitimate analysis.  They don't want to understand the details, but don't want to get in trouble for being an idiot later on.  If you don't know what you are doing, get a stats prof to bless your work.  Get some peer reviewed and published papers to point at.

EDIT:

Some references:

- http://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2012/tr597.pdf
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.cluster.html
- http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.903/abstract
- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/index.htm

The last reference is a great reference.  I find myself re-reading, pondering and using it a good bit.  There are good giants in there upon whose shoulders the act of standing gives good and rewarding vistas of vision into various veracities.

Comment: I will take a look at GMMS. What I meant by mainstream is frequently used, so I will find an existing library in my programming language of choice that contains the formulae etc etc.

Comment: There are GMM libraries for many languages.  Although I am just starting in "R", one of the advantages that I see in it is that its (extremely extensive) libraries are that they are for the most part created and certified by PhD's in stats/math.  Other languages, like Python, have wrappers for "R", so you might check that out too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, GMMs seem to be the correct tool for the job. Your earlier comment on not wanting to know the details, and not being shown up later is very true :) Are GMMs easy to use? They seem pretty complicated...

Comment: Joys of libraries.  I use MatLab.  I feed in the data, number of components, and number of replications (just to be sure of convergence) into it and it returns a structure that contains a number of things including AIC.  Personally I like to use about 30 replicates.  If I plot them out and there is low convergence rates, then I might look into regularization.  I doubt your data will be that ugly - it is likely to give clean results out the gate.  Use BIC to determine number of components in the cluster.  Look at mean distances.  Ask questions here too.

Comment: What happens if you are not sure of convergence?

Comment: So I will run the GMM fit ~30 times and look at the distribution of fits.  If the "best" BIC values happen in a cluster that is a substantial minority (6 or less of the 30) then I will introduce a small amount of regularization.  It is like ridge-regression.  It introduces a small bias (loss of distance between center of target and center of cluster of "shots") in exchange for large increase in precision (cluster width decrease).

Answer (score 1):

Questionary data is special, and many methods designed for continuous variables will not work well.

However, as you will likely not have millions of questionnaires, you can probably just use hierarchical clustering (try different linkages, maybe Ward) and a similarity coefficient that handles questionnaire data well; maybe try Gower's dissimilarity index first.

Unless you need a very scalable solution, hierarchical clustering is quite simple to implement yourself (so you can use your favorite similarity!). Plus, the dendrograms are a quite convenient visualization for small data sets.

Comment: There will only be absolute max a few thousand with the large corporates.

Comment: I do not know as much as I would like about dendrograms.  My first question is "how do you account for variability?".  The graph forms a visual "order statistic" but what is the uncertainty in the value?  What is the measure that indicates that your dendrogram is properly generalized?